# Remove "1 items" text in wishlist header icon count

Tags: magento2, wishlist, review

how can we remove the "items" text from the wishlist count I searched a bit and know the count is displayed from `app/design/frontend/.../.../Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml`

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter ? wishlist().items.length : '0'" class="counter qty">0</span>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only the text 'items' or the entire text with the count?

Comment: yes @CharmiPatel you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

- by the plugin
- by the preference
- by overriding phtml and js component

By the preference:

In di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="Dotsquares\Custom\Rewrite\CustomerData\Wishlist"/>
    </config>
```

Create Dotsquares\Custom\Rewrite\CustomerData\Wishlist.php

```
<?php

namespace Dotsquares\Custom\Rewrite\CustomerData;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\NotLoadInfoImageException;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Wishlist section
 */
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $wishlistHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $imageHelperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar
     */
    protected $block;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface
     */
    private $itemResolver;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface|null $itemResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($wishlistHelper, $block, $imageHelperFactory, $view, $itemResolver);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        $counter = str_replace(" item", "", str_replace(" items", "", $this->getCounter())) ;
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }
}
```

The best way to do this is by using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For **Remove "items" text** in wishlist header icon count follow below steps:

1.Create a di.xml file in the Vendor/Module/etc directory and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

2.Create a Wishlist.php file at Vendor/Module/CustomerData directory and add the below code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist as CoreWishlist;

class Wishlist extends CoreWishlist
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper, \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block, \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($wishlistHelper, $block, $imageHelperFactory, $view, $itemResolver);
    }

    /**
     * @param $count
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|null
     */
    protected function createCounter($count)
    {
        if ($count > 1) {
            //you can also add your custom text
            return __('%1', $count);
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            return __('1');
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3.then run the below commands and update wishlist,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

please check the result,

[image]

Let me know if you have any query.